# Diagnosticreports translated report portion lost (?) after clicking "Send to Apple"

Tags: macos, crash, logs

An app crashed, and I'm shown the crash reporter interface. I previewed the crash report and can see the translated version. After I click on the "Send to Apple" button, it seems like the translated portion is deleted and I'm left with the raw report which I can't read easily.

Is there any way to get the translated version back?